# Mac Firefox and CSS3 transitions

Tags: macos, firefox, css, css-transitions

My wife's blog (Japanese) has an issue with the styling of the comment form.
It looks fine on Windows Firefox and other browsers when you hover over the submit button (dark red) at the bottom. On Firefox for Macs, the hover effect is like 1/2 of the button gets the correct coloring while the bottom half. It looks fine in Mac Safari. Do I have some of my color properties wrong?
http://www.miwacle.com/?p=20246

Comment: For me, it appears to be the same on my Mac in Firefox 13, Safari 5 and Chrome 20. I see the red swipe down into a solid tanish colour. Does that sound right?

Comment: It looks the same for me between FF, Chrome, and Safari. I am using FF 13 on a MacBook Pro. Perhaps I am looking at the wrong button though because the page is in Japanese and I cannot read Japanese. Can you post screenshots of what you're seeing? Also, can you post the relevant code if possible?

Comment: Is the button the same when you are logged in and logged out? Maybe you are logged in with Firefox, and logged out with the others. What is your exact FF version?

Comment: @biziclop The original question said "latest Firefox", but I edited that out by accident. I'm guessing it should be FF13 or at least FF12, but that's a good question to ask nonetheless to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

try looking in here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions

this will give you the list of specific css for firefox.

hope this helps.

Comment: That's not at all what he was asking. His code is currently working fine except for a different OS's version of a browser.